# Log the IP-address of edits (AUDIT) in the Sitecore main log file

Tags: logging

A client wants to register the IP addresses in Sitecore logs for the AUDIT level, entries like item saved and item updates, is there a way to do that, those messages are OOTB.

Comment: Have you considered creating your own processor for those events? Then you can log whatever you want.

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid, you see all AUDIT logs that comes OOTB is fine by the client, only the IP info is missing, so the creating processor(s) for all the events (saving, creating etc.) just to redo all Audit messages with IP is my last solution to consider.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to overrided standard AUDIT messages. However, you could hook into Item events. Almost complete solution is described here: https://www.exsquared.com/blog/logging-changes-in-sitecore-made-by-content-authors/

Comment: Thank you @grg, I was looking to avoid that, I opened a ticket with Sitecore and they replied the same that Sitecore doesn't register the IP address. I'll end up creating event handlers for those events.